# How do I Install The GTA5 PLAY disk into a xbox360?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to be able to play GTA V without the disk in case I ever lose the disk or it becomes broken. If I could get some help that'll be terrific.

Comment: It's a security issue... What would stop you from installing the disk on your 360 and giving the disk to a friend so he can play too? And then he could do the same, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this can't be done. Even if you install both discs the Xbox 360 will require you have the play disc inserted in order to load the game. This does not apply to the digital version.

Note that GTA5 for Xbox 360 was optimized to stream data from several different locations simultaneously, so it's best not to install the play disc. [Here's some more information, for the curious.](http://kotaku.com/how-to-install-gta-v-on-xbox-360-without-hurting-perfor-1327503438)

Answer (score 2):

Installing games on your 360 console only allows the console to load and run the game faster.
You will always need the disc to start the game.

This goes for any xbox 360 game.